# Explanation of the idiom

Tags: idioms, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, connotations, idioms-in-context

> Both the mother and the father almost **turned themselves inside out** in embarrassment and apology.

Sometimes idioms make great difficulty to understand the text like this 'turned themselves inside out' one is quite difficult to comprehend. Is there any other way to re-construct the very sentence without changing its gist?

Comment: Have you done any research to see if you can find the meaning of this idiom? The third definition here is quite close: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+inside+out

Comment: Your title sounds like you want the idiom explained, which is fine, but the content of your question sounds like you want us to re-write your sentence, which we don't do on this site. Can you please edit your question to make it clear what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn sideways.

You can turn backwards.

If you are athletic and supple, you can stand on your head (turn upside down).

But, twist and turn as you may, there is no possible way to turn your insides into your outsides. The twisting and turning that you try in the effort may, however, be bizarre, extreme, or ridiculous and likely will provide great amusement to any spectators.

In this case, the idiom means “did laughably extreme things.”